# Property 'ariaHidden' does not exist

Tags: html, vue.js, nuxt.js

I am trying use area-hidden property on vue file as below, but it emit error.
(Also, data-dismiss emit similar error too)
Am I supposed to do additional set up to use area-hidden property?

```
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
</button>
```

Error:

```
Type '{ ariaHidden: string; "aria-hidden": "true"; }' is not assignable to type 'ElementAttrs<HTMLAttributes>'.
  Property 'ariaHidden' does not exist on type 'ElementAttrs<HTMLAttributes>'. Did you mean ''aria-hidden''?
```

If I need to provide more information, I am happy to do so.

Sorry for the noob question.
But I am struggling for hours..

Comment: Somewhere in your code you've written `ariaHidden` instead of `aria-hidden`. Find where and change the camelCase to kebab-case.

Answer (score 0):

this error coming from new version of volar extension ( 0.36 ), you can fix this error by downgrading volar to previous version. or wait for next update if they fix this